# Is it possible to connect telnet with curl interactively?

Tags: curl, telnet

Is it possible to use telnet in a interactive mode with curl?

When I connect with window's telnet command it does behave as a telnet client and I can interact with it.

Answer (score 4):

The following does what you're asking:

```
$ curl -vLI telnet://www.google.com:80/ <<< "GET /"
```

Additionally you can drop off the here string `<<< "GET /"` and type whatever HTTP commands you want to send to the server as if you were a browser.

Typically it's `GET / HTTP/1.1` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

An unusual way to phrase that question but, yes. Yes indeed. My personal favorites are (in no particular order):

#### [wuzz](https://github.com/asciimoo/wuzz) —

[image: wuzz screenshot]

#### [http-prompt](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt) (based on HTTPie) —

[image: http-prompt screenshot]

#### [httplab](https://github.com/gchaincl/httplab) (an interactive web *server*, not a client) —

[image: httplab screenshot]

Comment: These are great for HTTP with cURL but OP is asking about telnet with cURL not HTTP

Comment: You are correct. I'll keep my answer so i can find it when i google for these tools in a few months from now :)